# Jquery: is there a limit to how many functions can be called on a jquery object(method chaining)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example:
`$('#someObject').prev().children().first().click();`

Can jQuery handle this kind of code? Or do I have to break it into two (or more) lines after a certain point?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (almost) every function call on a jQuery object returns another jQuery object, so this can go on pretty much ad infinitum.

Comment: This is [`method chaining`](http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/introduction/method-chaining/).

Comment: Have you tried it? It should work to any extend your memory permits. If he methods returns an object it has the methods and can be used.

Comment: Yes i have. Turns out my issue was to do with a function returning a null object at a certain point in the line thus causing the remaining functions to fail. My first assumption about a limitation on method chaining was wrong

@PM77-1 77-1 thanks for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can continue to do this so long as the method returns a jQuery object.

For example, `.attr('class', 'test')` will return the same jQuery selection it was called on, meaning you can continue to chain more methods. However, `.attr('class')` will return a string representing the `class` attribute.

In your example case, yes, that should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

It does not seem to mention a limit. This is the guide from the jquery site

Chained Method Calls

When a chain of method calls is too long to fit on one line, there must be one call per line, with the first call on a separate line from the object the methods are called on. If the method changes the context, an extra level of indentation must be used.

http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/#chained-method-calls

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can. But I personally wouldn't do it in this way mainly to keep the code organized. Unless it would be extremely necessary. Also, take a look on .on(): It allows multiple handlers on one element, which would make it a bit more organized.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: You are saying you would do `$('#someObject').click(); $('#someObject').css({color:'red'}); $('#someObject').width(150)` instead of `$('#someObject').click().css({color:'red'}).width(150);`?

Comment: Doesn't make much sense suggesting a method, then linking to docs that say `on()` is preferred. `bind` will use `on()` internally anyway

Comment: Yes, @charlietfl, my bad. Just edited. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, no. I would not use them in the same line as long lines are worse to read.

Comment: @DavidsonSousa But performance-wise, your suggestion is *n* times slower, being *n* the number of lines -1. This means that the CSS parser would be called *n* times, to match though the DOM tree the same elements. Chaining and/or 'caching' the result of your selector solves the performance issue. I don't recommend breaking the chain, but you can put each method in a new line, keeping it readable and still maintaining your chain. ALL browsers will thank you for doing this way, and your users will be happy.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel "but you can put each method in a new line, keeping it readable and still maintaining your chain" - That's exactly what I meant.

Comment: The way you say it means the oposite.